# similar_text highest string value

Tags: php

I use similar_text to find which string have the highest similar value to the input

I tried using `rsort` to get the highest value, but how do I get string which have the highest value?

```
$similarities = [];
$input = "makanan daerah";
$type = array('pakaian','senjata','makanan', 'tarian');
foreach ($type as $value) {
    similar_text($input, $value, $percent);
    $similarities[$value] = $percent;
}
rsort($similarities);
echo($similarities[0]);
```

I expect output `makanan`
but the only output I can display is the percent value `66.6667`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try using `asort` to sort the associative array of terms and percentages by the latter.  Then, access the last key, which should coincide with the key having the highest percentage:

```
$similarities = [];
$input = "makanan daerah";
$type = array('pakaian','senjata','makanan', 'tarian');
foreach ($type as $value) {
    similar_text($input, $value, $percent);
    $similarities[$value] = $percent;
}
asort($similarities);
print_r($similarities);
end($similarities);
$key = key($similarities);
var_dump($key);

Array
(
    [senjata] => 19.047619047619
    [tarian] => 30
    [pakaian] => 47.619047619048
    [makanan] => 66.666666666667
)
string(7) "makanan"
```